# Yii validate without refresh page - LIKE/DISLIKE

Tags: ajax, validation, yii

I got 2 buttons like common like/dislike, each one sends 1 or 0 to the controller.
But each one refresh the page when users click it, and it's very anoying...

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id'=>'valorar-form',
                'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
                'action'=>array('/entradas/Valorar','id'=>$data->id)
        ));?>
                 <div >

                <button type="submit" style='margin: 5px;' name="rating" value="1">
                </button> 

                <button type="submit" style='margin: 5px;' name="rating" value="0">
                </button>
                 </div>
   <?php $this->i++; $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

On the controller Valorar action:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='valorar-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($valoracion);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
```

But nothing recived form $_POST['ajax']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `CActiveForm` in this case because you have no form elements. You could use 2 [`CHtml::ajaxButton()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxButton-detail) instead.

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxButton(
    '1', 
    array('entredas/valorar','id'=>$data->id),
    array(),
    array('style'=>'margin:5px', 'name'=>'rating')
) ?>
```

Comment: It seems like doesn't send or exec any action of 'Entradas' controller.

Comment: I need to submit the 0 or 1 value of the button, but not refresh the whole page.